# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect') with remote es module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dom, jsdelivr

### Error:

[image]

### Description:

I am playing with `esm.run` (es module cdn powered by jsdelivr), I want to import react directly from remote cdn.

With the help of `importmap`, the browser can transform from `import React from 'react'` to `import React from 'https://esm.run/react@18'`.

Then I got the above error with code provided below. Would be nice if anyone could help on this.

### Full code

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "react": "https://esm.run/react@18",
                    "react-dom": "https://esm.run/react-dom@18"
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script src="/dist/index.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### /dist/index.js (bundled)

```js
(function(){"use strict";try{if(typeof document!="undefined"){var e=document.createElement("style");e.appendChild(document.createTextNode("")),document.head.appendChild(e)}}catch(t){console.error("vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js",t)}})();
import require$$0 from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
var jsxRuntimeExports = {};
var jsxRuntime = {
  get exports() {
    return jsxRuntimeExports;
  },
  set exports(v) {
    jsxRuntimeExports = v;
  }
};
var reactJsxRuntime_production_min = {};
/**
 * @license React
 * react-jsx-runtime.production.min.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
var f = require$$0, k = Symbol.for("react.element"), l = Symbol.for("react.fragment"), m = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, n = f.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner, p = { key: true, ref: true, __self: true, __source: true };
function q(c, a, g) {
  var b, d = {}, e = null, h = null;
  void 0 !== g && (e = "" + g);
  void 0 !== a.key && (e = "" + a.key);
  void 0 !== a.ref && (h = a.ref);
  for (b in a)
    m.call(a, b) && !p.hasOwnProperty(b) && (d[b] = a[b]);
  if (c && c.defaultProps)
    for (b in a = c.defaultProps, a)
      void 0 === d[b] && (d[b] = a[b]);
  return { $$typeof: k, type: c, key: e, ref: h, props: d, _owner: n.current };
}
reactJsxRuntime_production_min.Fragment = l;
reactJsxRuntime_production_min.jsx = q;
reactJsxRuntime_production_min.jsxs = q;
(function(module) {
  {
    module.exports = reactJsxRuntime_production_min;
  }
})(jsxRuntime);
const jsx = jsxRuntimeExports.jsx;
const App = () => {
  require$$0.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("我是demo");
  }, []);
  return /* @__PURE__ */ jsx("div", { children: "我是demo rendssder" });
};
ReactDom.render(/* @__PURE__ */ jsx(App, {}), document.getElementById("root"));
export {
  App as default
};
```